# How to get video info from the current youtube video

Tags: javascript, youtube

I looked all over the internet, but found nothing. On the YouTube Website (In developer tools) I would like to pull the info from the current video.

`window.getPageData()` used to work but for some reason it disappeared

`window.ytInitialData` only has the data for the video when the page first loads.

I have looked everywhere. Please help!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Maybe you want to look into using the [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3).

Comment: @Ace I'm making a simple youtube downloader in the form of a javascript bookmarklet
https://github.com/ethanaobrien/youtube-downloader
I dont think the youtube api would help, thanks though!

Comment: Interesting, never heard of bookmarlets before, seems cool. Anyway, I posted an answer.

Comment: What info do you need to get about the video? Maybe you can get it from the html/url?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.ytplayer.config.args.raw_player_response.videoDetails
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @AlFoиceѫ I feel you, but at the same time, Idk what more context I can give. He asked for a location, I provided the location.

Comment: `window.ytplayer` returns `{ }` (An empty json string)

Comment: @EthanO'Brien Hmm, it's possible it gest emptied for some reason... I tried it on a page that was open for a long time and it was empty, but it was there after a refresh.